# how to setup svn repository for http with username and password

Tags: apache, http, authentication, svn, svnserve

i have created a svn repository hosting websites.

when user checkout using 
`svn://svn@sub_dom.domain.com/sub_dom/xyz` 
then it will ask for username and password.

but when user check out using  
`http://sub_dom.domain.com/svn/xyz` 
is does not ask username or password.

`my scenario`

- There is master admin who have all authority for creating repo and manage svn permission.
- master admin can create project admin, users. and master admin grant permission for repository.
- different user may have different permission for different projects.
- there are multiple master admin, and they have multiple repositories

Folder stucture 
`all_repo_dir
   sub_dom1
      repo1
      repo2
   sub_dom2
      repo8
      repo9`

i want something like 
`http://demo.repositoryhosting.com/svn/demo_django-app`

above is working repository.

i want svnserve to check repo/conf/svnserve.conf when user do checkout using http link.

so please tell me where am i going wrong ?